# Android ADA Compliance

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm currently developing an application, and my client would like it to be ADA compliant. I've looked into Android Accessibility on the documentation and I'm having partial success. I downloaded Talkback to my android phone and the device will read out each Activity title, but it wont read the onscreen text(within a textview). I've tried to set the content descirption within the textview XML like this:

```
 android:contentDescription="@string/terms_conditions"
```

However, it wont read the text from the text view for me. Is there something else I should be declaring?

Comment: I just tried using TalkBack on my app and it reads out all the text in my TextViews without any problems. Not to sound patronizing, but... have you tried tapping the on the text?

Comment: Oh,wow, I should of closed this. The issue was my version of android was to old on the device I had been testing on. I used a newer version, 3.0+ I think and it worked.